# Can I stay in France more than the validity range of my Schengen visa given I'm not exceeding my duration limit?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, schengen-visas

I recently applied for a short-term student visa, mentioning the departure and return dates as 13/05/18 and 10/08/18 (=90 days) respectively. After my visa got approved, the validity dates mentioned were 11/05/18 and 08/08/18 (=90 days) but since I have already booked my return flight on 10/08/18 and if I return back from France on 10//08/18 I'll be violating the visa policy.

What will be the best thing which I can do in this scenario?

If I go with this visa and violate the visa policy by exceeding the visa's validity by 2 days what consequences can I possibly face, considering the face that it wasn't actually my fault but a sheer mistake committed by people in embassy?

Comment: If you think there is a mistake, you're supposed to bring it to the attention of the consulate. That excuse is not going to let you off the hook if you violate  the terms of the visa.

Comment: @TheZealot I have my departure flight on 17th May (a rescheduled one), and I am sure that if they reprocess there mistake it's gonna take much more time.

Comment: @JVJ Have you tried contacting the visa issuer and asking them to change it? Overstaying isn’t a good idea, you could be fined on exit

Comment: Like The Zealot said, it's your responsibility to respond to the error. The duration limit does not apply to you because it's the visa end date that matters here. It's also risky to ever buy tickets before the visa is issued: it could have been refused!

Comment: @Traveller I'll try calling them tomorrow, I received my visa today itself. All in all, I am left with very less time, lets see how they'll respond.

Comment: @user16259 Visa application itself required me to, attach the flight tickets as supporting document. So I had no option, other than to get flight tickets booked in advance.

Comment: @JVJ Next time book a ticket and then print out your schedule and then **cancel it immediately within the 24 hour free cancellation period**. All they want is the printout for their records. That's what I've been doing the past twenty plus years.

Comment: @TheZealot Thanks for this suggestion! I was literally unaware of this, after all this is my first international journey, will surely do the same next time.

Comment: @The Zealot I don’t doubt your excellent advice - but what a ridiculously futile process!

Comment: @Traveller I also find it extremely unnecessary, however I guess by the Schengen rules they need documented evidence of your travel. With visas, you have to give them what they want. They know themselves it's a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @traveller 's suggestion, I contacted the French Embassy here in India. They asked me to visit Embassy asap and get the problem solved. Lastly, they issued a new VISA with the correct valid dates and nullified the previous one, and without any additional charges.

Enjoying here in Paris! :)